# jq merge arrays inside object

Tags: bash, jq

I have two objects

```
{
    "a": [
        "1-1",
        "1-2"
    ],
    ...
}
```

and

```
{ 
    "a": [
        "2-1",
        "2-2",
        "2-3"
    ],
    ...
}
```

there are other keys in both objects, but I don't care for them.

What I want to get is the object where elements of `"a"` will be concatenated:

```
{
    "a": [
        "1-1",
        "1-2",
        "2-1",
        "2-2",
        "2-3"
    ],
    ...
}
```

other keys can be replaced/merged/doesn't matter.

How do I do this with `jq`?

Comment: Do you have one or two input files?

Comment: @hek2mgl I actually want to use it as `echo '{...}' '{...}' | jq ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the -s command-line option:

```
jq -s '.[1].a as $a1 | .[0] | (.a += $a1)'
```

Since you don't care about the non-a keys, an alternative would be:

```
jq -n '{a: (input.a + input.a)}'
```

Notice the `-n` option in the line above.