# jq to merge several objects in an array to one

Tags: json, jq

I have a series of json files that I want to extract some information from and stick into CSVs using jq. The data I need look something like this:

```
[{"content":"Apples","_id":"7OLZ","type":"fruit}, 
{"content":"Oranges","_id":"5BHY","type":"fruit"},
{"content":"Pears","_id":"DJQD","type":"fruit"}]
```

I want to be able to combine just the fruit values into a string without the other keys and occupy one cell in a spreadsheet. The files can also have a variable number of fruits in the array.

`"Apples Oranges Pears"`

Is this doable? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50569174/jq-merge-arrays-inside-object) on SO comes close, I think, but as someone who doesn't work with json data or jq a whole lot, I couldn't piece together what the solution was actually doing.

Many thanks for any insight

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is stored as j.json

```
[{
                "content": "Apples",
                "_id": "7OLZ",
                "type": "fruit"
        },
        {
                "content": "Oranges",
                "_id": "5BHY",
                "type": "fruit"
        },
        {
                "content": "Pears",
                "_id": "DJQD",
                "type": "fruit"
        }
]
```

this command will help.

```
jq '.[] | [.content] | join(",") '    j.json
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution puts all of the values for the "content" key into an array and then joins the elements of the array with a space.

```
jq '[.[] | .content ]|join(" ")'
```

Output: `"Apples Oranges Pears"`

Given that [the definition of map(x)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions) is `[.[] | x]`, this is equivalent.

```
jq 'map(.content)|join(" ")'
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to combine just the fruit values

Presumably therefore you will want to check `.type`, e.g.

```
jq -r 'map(select(.type=="fruit").content) | join(" ")'
```